# Javascript to get the id of the hyperlink clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to know how i can set the current hyperlink id to a hidden field on clicking the corresponding links. The html control code is as follows:

```
<a href="#TB_inline?height=155&width=300&inlineId=hiddenModalContent" class="thickbox" id="ExpressionsLink"
          title="Create expression column" onclick="keepID()">Add Expressions Model</a> 
           <a href="#TB_inline?height=155&width=300&inlineId=hiddenModalContent" class="thickbox" id="AggregateMethodLink"
          title="Create aggregate column">Add Aggregate Methods</a><input id="HiddenIdHolder" 
          type="hidden" />
```

I need the id of the link clicked on the hidden field 'HiddenIdHolder'.

Javascript

```
 function keepID() {
     var hiddenInput = document.getElementById("HiddenIdHolder");
     hiddeninput.value= ? // What can i do here to get the id?
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` refers to the element itself. **[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nCtsF/)**

```
onclick="keepID(this)"
```

Then

```
function keepID(element)
{
    var hiddenInput = document.getElementById("HiddenIdHolder");
    hiddeninput.value = element.getAttribute("id");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $('#HiddenIdHolder').val($(this).attr('id'))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your HTML to provide argument for KeepID function:

```
<a href="#xxx" onclick="KeepID(this);">ooxx</a>
```

note that you should provide a `this` argument when invoke KeepID function, then in KeepID function, you can access this  element from argument:

```
function KeepID(src) {
    document.getElementById("HiddenIdHolder").value = src.id;
}
```